# On demand decorator?

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have a decorator called `Timer`, now ideally, to use a decorator like so:

```
@Timer
def function(...):
    return None
```

However, this calls Timer *all the time* `function` is called. Now of course you can use a decorator like a normal function to do this, when you want to call it under a particular instance:

```
function = Timer(function)
```

However, this does not look pretty (I'm picky, I know). So, is there a way to wrap a decorator over a function for say all use cases in a testing file or something? So, something like:

```
from app import cheese

@Timer  # Syntax error
cheese  # Syntax error
```

Note, that it only uses the decorator for this particular file, and not all the time, if you had placed it above the actual function definition.

Comment: decorator syntax can only be used before `def` and `class`.  is there some reason you can't just use the desugared variant?

Comment: @dequestarmappartialsetattr No, Its just that it does not look very nice on my code, and if there was a better way of doing this, then I wanted to know.

Comment: I can only *assume* this targets some kind of call-point specific performance logging (stating the use-case helps in such cases). It probably can be done (for your own code), involving some dirty stack frame hacks and with some time penalty (which can be kept out of performance data). OTOH, the profile hooks are there for exactly this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can enable/disable at the top of the file (i.e. you know when you load the file whether you want them enabled or not), you can use the [Enable/Disable Decorator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Enable.2FDisable_Decorators).

if not... you didn't post the source for the decorator, but there's no reason it couldn't reference a global variable for enable/disable in the wrapping code itself. i.e. a decorator looks like this:

```
@simple_decorator
def my_simple_logging_decorator(func):
    def you_will_never_see_this_name(*args, **kwargs):
        print 'calling {}'.format(func.__name__)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return you_will_never_see_this_name
```

(from https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary)

Simply add in a guard for the added code i.e.

```
@simple_decorator
def my_simple_logging_decorator(func):
    def you_will_never_see_this_name(*args, **kwargs):
# Added/modified code starts here
        if globalvar:
            print 'calling {}'.format(func.__name__)
# End modified code
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return you_will_never_see_this_name
```